# Cómo puedo crear una función donde el nombre de la taula sea un paràmetro

Tags: oracle

deseo crear una función que me permita saber si una VIEW tiene o no registros en ORACLE. Querria entrar la VIEW como parámetro. He intentado:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION te_registres (v_taula IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
CURSOR c_taula IS
SELECT null FROM te_registres_taula;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create or replace synonym te_registres_taula for ' || v_taula;
    OPEN c_taula;
    IF c_taula%notfound THEN
        RETURN 'NO';
    END IF;
    CLOSE c_taula;
    RETURN 'SI';
END te_registres;
```

Pero cuando la ejecuto me da el error ORA-14552: no es pot realitzar un DDL, commit o rollback dins d'una consulta o DML

Alguna idea de cómo hacerlo? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si quieres saber si hay registros ¿para qué usas `CREATE`?

Comment: Tal como te comentan, el error es claro: *no es posible realizar un [DDL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenguaje_de_definici%C3%B3n_de_datos) (create, drop, alter, por ejemplo) dentro de una consulta o [DML](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenguaje_de_manipulaci%C3%B3n_de_datos)*.

Comment: Intento saber si un conjunto de vistas devuelven registros. Para ello uso una nueva vista con SELECT anidados que me devuelvan el primer registro si es que hay primer registro.

Mi primera idea era usar ```SELECT 'view_name_1' FROM view_name_1 FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY UNION SELECT 'view_name_2' FROM view_name_2 FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY UNION ... ````  
pero no puedo anidar instrucciones con FETCH FIRST y necesito usar ROWNUM = 1. 
Así la vista es muy poco eficiente. Por eso he pensado en crear una función en que cambie la vista de la cuál pregunto si tiene registros.

Comment: Perdonar el formateado, no consigo hacerlo bien

Answer (score 0):

Ya he solucionado el problema a través de un cursor dinámico:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION te_registres (
    v_taula IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS

    v_query  VARCHAR2(500);
    v_camp   NUMBER(1, 0);
    TYPE t_cursor IS REF CURSOR;
    c_taula  t_cursor;
BEGIN
    v_query := 'SELECT 1 camp FROM ' || v_taula;
    OPEN c_taula FOR v_query;

    FETCH c_taula INTO v_camp;
    IF c_taula%notfound THEN
        RETURN 'NO';
    END IF;
    CLOSE c_taula;
    RETURN 'SI';
END te_registres;
```